# Javascript collision detection on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, collision-detection, game-physics

I am struggling with writing collision detection for the sword and the enemy.  Attempting to implement coordinates for the sword using variable swdX and swdY have caused the sword to morph rather than follow the character and maintain shape.

The collision code I am using is

```
//subtract hp enemy on sword swing
if (swdX == enmX){
    enmhplevel--;
}
```

However, my output for swdX never shows swdX as changing.

A link can be found here.

http://jsfiddle.net/Qt7zd/3/

Pointy -  All of my code is on the JSfiddle.  I tried updating the loop with

```
swdX == posX +80;
swdY == posY -40;
```

however, this does not update the coordinates. Do you have any pointers?

Comment: Is that all your code? Nothing ever assigns a new value to "swdX" after it is initialized; why do you expect it to change?

Comment: 'have broken the sword' is not exactly a very accurate description of the problem. As it stands, I would recommend a blacksmith.

Comment: Carpetsmoker.  Stop smoking carpet and you might realize a blacksmith is of little use with computers.

Comment: I recommend you to use bacon.js

Answer (score 0):

Adding `swdX = posX +80; swdY = posY -40;` into the loop does update the coordinates fine. In you question however, you have `==`, which is not assignment, it is an equals operator.

Then your collision detection in this example needs be expanded to accommodate the radius of the enemy (so the sword hits if the point is anywhere inside the enemy, not just perfectly on it's center), and the angle of the sword (so it doesnt hit when the sword is rotating somewhere not on the enemy).

```
if ((swdX >= enmX - 30 || swdX > enmX + 30) && (Z % 360 >= 10 && Z % 360 < 60)) {
    enmhplevel--;
}
```

You'd definitely need to get rid of the hardcoded constants, consider the y direction, consider when the point of the sword is through the enemy, etc, for a game, but the example is working here: http://jsfiddle.net/j84zU/